How to Pass a Clicked On Element ID to jQuery Function To Do Something With Another Element?
How can you pass the ID of an element that is clicked on to manipulate another corresponding element, without having to write a jQuery function for every single one?
So.... Let's say that I have a list of some stuff (headlines, events, etc.) on a page. I show a headline then have a link that says "more" after each headline to hide/show the details of the headline or event or whatever. So it looks something like this...
<div id="SomeBlock"> Some text and stuff goes here    
<a id="MoreDetailsLink1">More...</a>
<div id="MoreDetailsDiv1" style="display:none;">The rest of story goes here</div>
</div>

I know I should be able write:
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#MoreDetailsLink1").click(function(){
            $("#MoreDetailsDiv1").toggle(); 
        });
    });

But, let's say that I have 25 or 100 of those headline/details elements. I really do not want to rewrite a jQuery function for every single one. I should be able to do something to pass or grab the "More..." link id to toggle the correct more details div.
How do I do that? If I click on the "MoreDetailsLink47", I need the "MoreDetailsDiv47" div to toggle. I am just not sure at all, how to write it so that when the "more" is clicked on the appropriate more details div will be manipulated.
One more quick note, yes (especially if it makes it simpler), in this example all the elements will have the same prefix name, just the numbers will change.

@Yogi unfortunately, in this case, it's a little bit more complicated that that.

HTML:
<div class="EventDetailsLinks">
<a data-target="MoreDetailsDiv172" id="MoreDetailsLink172" class="MoreLink" style="cursor:pointer">&nbsp;<b>&bull; More...</b></a>
</div>
<div id="MoreDetailsDiv172" class="MoreDetailsDiv">
More Stuff Goes here
</div>

JavaScript:
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.MoreLink').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default action of the link
    var targetDivId = $(this).data('target'); // Get the target div ID from the data attribute
    $('#' + targetDivId).toggle(); // Toggle the visibility of the target div
    });
});


While it would be possible to achieve what you require in the manner you suggest, ie. passing id attributes around to various method calls, the far better approach would be to follow DRY principles.
To do this, use the same class attributes on your repeated HTML structure, where just the content changes. From there you can attach the same event handler to all those elements. Within that event handler you can traverse the DOM to find content based on the pre-determined structure, instead of targeting elements with incremental id attributes.
Below is a working example of how to do this - note that the single jQuery event handler will work for an infinite number of the .some-block structures.


jQuery($ => {
  $(".more-details-toggle").on('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(e.target).siblings('.more-details').toggle();
  });
});
.more-details {
  display: none;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some-block">
  Some text and stuff goes here
  <a class="more-details-toggle" href="#">More...</a>
  <div class="more-details">The rest of story goes here</div>
</div>
<div class="some-block">
  Some text and stuff goes here
  <a class="more-details-toggle" href="#">More...</a>
  <div class="more-details">The rest of story goes here</div>
</div>
<div class="some-block">
  Some text and stuff goes here
  <a class="more-details-toggle" href="#">More...</a>
  <div class="more-details">The rest of story goes here</div>
</div>




I tried applying your solution and I cannot seem to be able to get it to work.
Here is the actual page that I am trying it on https://wvsr.club/events#UpcomingCalendar

Unfortunately I'm not able to debug your attempted code without seeing it. Try checking the console within browser devtools for errors you can fix, and if that doesn't work, put the relevant HTML/JS/CSS in a https://jsfiddle.net and drop a link here.
